# Can't import module on commandline

Tags: python, import, module

After pip installing, in python I can import this [module](https://github.com/karan/HackerNewsAPI) if I start terminal interactively , but I get an error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name HN
```

if I save everything in a .py file and run it from the commandline. 
Why is this and how can I solve it?

Thanks.

Code:

```
from hn import HN

hn = HN()

# print the first 2 pages of newest stories
for story in hn.get_stories(story_type='newest', page_limit=2):
    print story.rank, story.title
```

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: Do the interactive terminal and `.py` run (from commandline) occur as the same user?

Comment: getting started code. See above. Thanks.

Comment: can you `import hn` in script? how many pythons do you have installed?

Comment: And what is your `.py` file called? (I hope it isn't `hn.py`)

Comment: @RedBaron Thanks !!! What a stupid error. LOL. Sorry to waste your time. Yes I called it hn.py. Brilliant me :)

Comment: User made a typo in code and you ask me to explain it like it's a big deal or sth.